# Is there a theoretical limit to the splitting of atomic energy levels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, perturbation-theory

We know that the hyper fine interaction is due to interactions between the nucleus and the electron and Zeeman splitting induces further quantization but what I am wondering is, are there any higher order perturbations that may contribute to further level splitting or is there a derivable limit?

Comment: Are you asking only about perturbations in an isolated atom out alone in space? Or including external fields and interactions with the surrounding atoms?

Comment: I was mostly thinking about the contribution from external fields but if there is some mechanism where greater splitting occurs for an isolated atom--beyond the hyper fine interaction--I would like to know about that as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, adding external fields or interactions with nearby objects can dramatically alter the electronic structure of an atom, especially the valence band. A magnetic field can cause splitting through the Zeeman effect, there can also be splitting due to an electric field, called the [Stark effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark_effect) or the [Autler-Townes effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autler%E2%80%93Townes_effect) for AC fields. You might also be interested in the [Lamb shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamb_shift).

If you are near other atoms there can be other effects. Chemical bonding is clearly a rearranging of the electronic energy states caused by an external perturbation. But also within a material the nearby atoms will affect the electronic structure.